# Rails: Permission denied for File.delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, permissions

I am creating a very simple web app that allows the user to upload a .zip file that I temporarily save in the tmp folder inside my application, parse the contents using zipfile and then delete the file after I'm done.

I managed to upload the file and copy it to the tmp folder, I can successfully parse it and get the results I want, but when I try to delete the file I get a permission denied error.

here's my view:

```
<%= form_tag({action: :upload}, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :software %>
  <br/><br/>
  <%= submit_tag("UPLOAD") %>
<% end %>
```

And here's my controller:

```
def upload    
  @file = params[:software]
  @name = @file.original_filename

  File.open(Rails.root.join('tmp', @name), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(@file.read)
  end    
  parse
  File.delete("tmp/#{@name}")
  render action: "show"
end
```

I have tried using `FileUtils.rm ("tmp/#{@name}")` as well, and I also tried setting `File.chmod(0777, "tmp/#{@name}")` before deletion but to no avail. Changing the deletion path to `Rails.root.join('tmp', @name)` like the `File.open` block also doesn't fix it. I can totally delete the file via console so I don't know what can be the matter.

EDIT: The parse method:

```
def parse
  require 'zip'
  Zip::File.open("tmp/#{@nome}") do |zip_file|   
    srcmbffiles = File.join("**", "src", "**",  "*.mbf")
    entry = zip_file.glob(srcmbffiles).first
    @stream = entry.get_input_stream.read
    puts @stream
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that for some reason my file was not being closed for deletion in either the `File.open` block or the `Zip::File.open` block. My solution was to close it manually and avoid using open blocks, changing this snippet:

```
File.open(Rails.root.join('tmp', @name), 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(@file.read)
end
```

into this:

```
f = File.open(Rails.root.join('tmp', @nome), 'wb+') 
f.write(@file.read)   
f.close
```

and changing my parse method from this:

```
def parse
  require 'zip'
  Zip::File.open("tmp/#{@nome}") do |zip_file|   
    srcmbffiles = File.join("**", "src", "**",  "*.mbf")
    entry = zip_file.glob(srcmbffiles).first
    @stream = entry.get_input_stream.read
    puts @stream
  end
end
```

to this:

```
def parse
  require 'zip'
  zf = Zip::File.open("tmp/#{@nome}")
  srcmbffiles = File.join("**", "src", "**",  "*.mbf")
  entry = zf.glob(srcmbffiles).first
  @stream = zf.read(entry)
  puts @stream  
  zf.close()    
end
```

Notice that I changed the way I populate `@stream` because apparently `entry.get_input_stream` also locks the file you're accessing.

Answer (score 1):

The writing process may be still locking the file.  You may have to wait until that process is complete.

Comment: I just tried putting `sleep(30)` right before deletion and it's still no good. Is there a more correct way to wait for the writing process to be done?

Comment: Ensure the file is being closed after the parse process.  30ms may not be enough time ... you may need a loop a couple times until the file system is finished with that file

Comment: That `sleep` function waits in seconds, so that was 30 seconds... And my `File.open` block closes the file upon ending, so I don't think it's that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

'"tmp/#{@name}"' is not right path. Just use 'Rails.root.join('tmp', @name)'

Comment: That seems to be the case, yes, but even with the changed path the same error happens.

Comment: can you please provide "parse" method?

Comment: Absolutely. Edited it in. It finds a specific file inside my .zip and puts the contents of it in a variable. It works fine and I assume it closes the file upon ending the `Zip::File.open` block

Comment: try instead of saving and deleting file in the tmp folder just use original uploaded tempfile. According documentation the lifespan of this file is short.   http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile

Comment: moofkit, the file gets uploaded to the Windows Temp folder. Is there a way I can use `Zip::File.open` to access it without bringing it into my application the way I'm doing here?